# Recovering a single fille from Nandroid backup?

Tags: rom-flashing, data-recovery, twrp

I used TWRP to backup whole system and copy the backup to my computer. I would like to gain access to a single file. Is there a way I can do this without flashing the whole image? I'm not sure which backup it was in exactly so this could be a very lengthy process and was wondering any tips?

Answer (score 0):

use Titanium backup pro to extract the single app or data, through extract from nandroid backup(your backup must be in sdcard/twrp/backups)

Comment: So TI Backup Pro can extract from TWRP backups?

Answer (score 0):

[Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) does exactly what you want for free, but it also has a pro version with additional features.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these nandroid backups are in some wrapper format of zip or tar.gz

use your archiver application in computer to extract that backup or use Titanium backup to restore a particular app from a backup